# How can specify an object in Python?

Tags: python, object

For example,

```
asdf=turtle.Turtle()
asdf1=asdf.clone()
asdf2=asdf.clone()
asdf3=asdf.clone()
a=random.randrange(1, 4)
asdf[a].goto(0, 0)
```

like this, I want to specify object, and move it.
Is there a way to do this? Or should I just repeat the if-else syntax?

Comment: taking a wild guess here, but do you mean `random.choice([asdf1, asdf2, asdf3, asdf4]).goto(0, 0)`?

Comment: yup, maybe that was right.

Comment: You need a _collection_, like a list or a dictionary. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables